# What are the fundamental differences between speech and music in frequency domain?

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, speech

What are the fundamental differences between speech and music in the **frequency domain?**

I can think mainly of features in the time domain that can differentiate speech from music signals, e.g. short silences [[Wolfe2002Speech](https://phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/ICMPC.pdf)].

Maybe fundamental frequency could be used for distinguishing speech from music? If yes then what would be typical ranges of $F_0$ for speech and music?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to look at the energy below 80 Hz. Unless you have a recording of James Earl Jones, there will be almost none for speech and any music with bass and/or drums is going to have a lot down there.

Note that there is huge variability in music recording and a lot in speech. Creating an algorithm that can reliably distinguish between the two for the majority all recordings is a fairly complicated. Looking at the "average spectrum" isn't that useful since the any individual instance can (and does) look completely different than the "average spectrum". This is actually a good candidate for machine learning although many deterministic algorithms do exist as well.

Comment: I would think rap music could be especially challenging.

Answer (score 0):

(using only the average magnitude spectrum):

- music often fills in all the spectrum, especially more modern music. Speech is mostly in the mid frequencies
- in almost all music there is a dominant key. And frequencies at this tone and its overtones will be prevalent enough to cause peaks.